# Streams Concatenation error

Tags: c#, stream

I have two streams that i want to combine into one stream. The first stream is user-defined **stringStream** class that inherits from System.IO.Stream class and the second stream is a **networkStream** , I created an array of Stream with stores those two streams and pass it to a user-defined class **combinedStream** constructor as parameter. Below are the lines of code

```
StringStream stringStream = new StringStream("test string");
Stream[] streamArray = new Stream[2];
streamArray[0] = stringStream;
streamArray[1] = nsStream;//NetworkStream instance parameter
CombinedStream combinedStream = new CombinedStream(streamArray);
this.nsStream = (NetworkStream)combinedStream;
```

This the error i got : "Cannot convert CombinedStream to NetworkStream" 
What could be the reason?

Comment: Because it's not a network stream? Does CombinedStream inherit from NetworkStream? Does your nsStream member need to be a NetworkStream or could you use a more general stream interface that CombinedStream does implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly simply, because `CombinedStream` (which is presumably your own class) is *not* a `NetworkStream`. I wouldn't *expect* it to be.

The big question is why `nsStream` is meant to be a `NetworkStream` anyway. Can you change the type so it's just `Stream` instead? That should be fine *unless* you're using any `NetworkStream`-specific methods... and if you're doing that, then what would you expect to happen when those methods were called on a `CombinedStream`?

Comment: I am developing an **http application** in which one class has a  read method meant to read a NetworkStream and this method sets the instance variable nsStream to a CombinedStream( another class that inherits from Stream class).

Comment: @Xris: But why does `nsStream` have to be a `NetworkStream`? Does it need anything specifically from `NetworkStream`?

Comment: The only reason i used a networkStream is because i initially created a class that instantiate a tcp connection from socket and with socket i am able to create a networkStream object too that i can read!

Comment: @Xris: This is precisely why it's often good to declare a variable with the least specific type that you really require - it means you can change the *actual* type you use for a compatible one later.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `CombinedStream` is not defined as a subclass of `NetworkStream`. Thus the last line: `this.nsStream = (NetworkStream)combinedStream;` will fail as an invalid conversion.